Maintenance Plans Failing Invalid Class String
This is on a SQL Server 2017.  We are required to use maintenance plans for full/log backups and DBCC Checks.  They have been working fine, but I received an email that they have failed yesterday.  I see all jobs not based on maintenance plans are fine, but all jobs based from a maintenance plan fail.  They are set for the SA account as owner and running as SQL Server Agent.  Service accounts are running and accounts have permissions as I can run them manually just fine. Wrote to a output log for more details:

Started:  12:00:01 PM
Could not load package "Maintenance Plans\Log" because of error 0x800401F3.
Description: Invalid class string
Source: 
Started:  12:00:01 PM
Finished: 12:00:01 PM
Elapsed:  0.219 seconds\
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 14.0.3465.1 for 64-bit\
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.\

I did install SSMS 20 yesterday, but then re-installed SSMS 19 and still have the issue.  I'm not sure if it's related.  I updated SSMS to 20 on many other database servers without any problems, but those were running SQL Server 2019.
I'm not finding much on the web.  Has anyone seen this before?
Thanks

Are you on the latest CU of SQL Server 2017? Does creating a new Maintenance Plan work? Were any updates installed on that server just before it broke?

I am on the latest CU of SQL Server 2017.  I can create a new maintenance plan successfully, but it will also fail to execute via schedule or manually.  I updated to SSMS 20 and it started to occur.  Then uninstalled and went back to SSMS 19 and the issue continues.

You upgrading SSMS client versions on your local machine shouldn't be related at all. Unless  you're saying you updated it on the server running your SQL instance.

I did update it on the server running the instance.  Unfortunately I am forced to RDP to it and use SSMS on the server due to firewall restrictions.

Sounds like you guys have a security hole if the default port is blocked for a regular database connection, but you're allowed to RDP to it. I know that's outside your control, but food for thought for whoever at your company decided on that. In any case, I could only recommend trying to rollback the update and / or restore the server itself to the point in time prior to those SSMS updates. But I'd still be surprised if that's what caused the issue.

Yes, our cyber dept doesn't make sense!  I found on MS SSMS page that SQL 2017 uses legacy integration services for maintenance plans and use should use SSMS 17.  I tried that, and it worked.  It was working with SSMS 18 and 19, but broke at 20.   Thought I would update in case someone else had this issue.

You should post that as answer to your own question and accept it so others see it more prominently. Glad you found a solution albeit odd, especially since it was previously working with later versions of SSMS. But maybe reinstalling 17 fixed one of the components that the 20 installer broke.
